# dotmailer request token from REST API

Tags: rest, dotmailer

I struggle in call the REST API at Dotmailer.

he provide a document for call the OAuth and get the token. 
but it's always throws the same error.

**Input is**

Post Method
URI: https://r1-app.dotmailer.com/OAuth2/Tokens.ashx
JSON input is 

`{
    "client_id" : "apiuser-XXXXXXXXXXX@apiconnector.com",
    "redirect_uri" : null,
    "client_secret" : "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "grant_type": "authorization_code",
    "code":"MyServerCode",
    "test_mode":true
}`

**Out put is**

`{
  "error": "invalid_request",
  "error_description": "There was a problem with the 'grant_type' parameter: The parameter is required."
}`

Anyone know the error.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Hello. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look around and take the [tour], and read through the [help center]. You can also read about [ask] a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Dotmailer OAuth have some problem. 
I was used alternatively **Basic Authentication** method to access the dotmailer API.

Base URI = https://api.dotmailer.com/v2/ 
**Header** 

 `Content-type: application/json
 Authorization: Basic base64_convertion(username:password).`

**Sample**

 `Content-type: application/json
 Authorization: Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.`


Use WADL method. 
https://api.dotmailer.com/v2/help/wadl